# Inconsistent Result in DigestUtils.md5(String data) Method for the Same String

Tags: java, apache-commons

Hi In My application I need to calcluate the md5 Hash Value for a string value... for that I have called `DigestUtils.md5Hex(String string)` method... But it is not produced same result always for a same string... The result is inconsistent. In that `md5Hex()` method internally  **md5(string)** called. That method returns the different byteArray values for a same string. I am not able to get what exactly happening? Please clarify the issue...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can guess, this is not possible. You are probably passing different strings, but you don't know it. They may differ by a whitespace, for example, or some invisible character.

Comment: As your point of view, How can I identify the Invisible character... And from my side the string which i passed is getting from the result of java code. (For Example the string is getting from the file content). How it is possible the same string is not getting from a same file(without change anything in the file)?

Comment: are the two strings equal (using `.equals(..)` ? You can output the backing character array as ints, and compare the codes